# How can I change the orientation of a .pdf document from Portrait to Landscape in Python

Tags: python

I want to change the orientation of a .pdf document from Portrait to Landscape using Python. Below is the code for my attempt on this.

The solution is not giving me the expected result. Anyone with an answer?

```py
def viewDocumentInvoice(request, slug):
    #fetch that invoice
    try:
        invoice = Invoice.objects.get(slug=slug)
        pass
    except:
        messages.error(request, 'Something went wrong')
        return redirect('invoices')

    #fetch all the products - related to this invoice
    products = Product.objects.filter(invoice=invoice)

    #Get Client Settings
    p_settings = Settings.objects.get(clientName='Kamrate Nigeria Limited')

    #Calculate the Invoice Total
    invoiceTotal = 0.0
    if len(products) > 0:
        for x in products:
            y = float(x.quantity) * float(x.price)
            invoiceTotal += y

    context = {}
    context['invoice'] = invoice
    context['products'] = products
    context['p_settings'] = p_settings
    context['invoiceTotal'] = "{:.2f}".format(invoiceTotal)
    # context['y'] = "{:.2f}".format(y)

    #The name of your PDF file
    filename = '{}.pdf'.format(invoice.uniqueId)  

    #HTML FIle to be converted to PDF - inside your Django directory
    template = get_template('invoice/pdf-template.html')

    #Render the HTML
    html = template.render(context)

    #Options - Very Important [Don't forget this]
    options = {
          'encoding': 'UTF-8',
          'javascript-delay':'10', #Optional
          'enable-local-file-access': None, #To be able to access CSS
          'page-size': 'A4',
          'custom-header' : [
              ('Accept-Encoding', 'gzip')
          ],
      }
      #Javascript delay is optional

    #Remember that location to wkhtmltopdf
    #config = pdfkit.configuration(wkhtmltopdf='/usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf')
    config = pdfkit.configuration(wkhtmltopdf='C:\Program Files\wkhtmltopdf/bin\wkhtmltopdf.exe')

    #IF you have CSS to add to template
    css1 = os.path.join(settings.CSS_LOCATION, 'assets', 'css', 'bootstrap.min.css')
    css2 = os.path.join(settings.CSS_LOCATION, 'assets', 'css', 'dashboard.css')

    #Create the file
    file_content = pdfkit.from_string(html, False, configuration=config, options=options)

    # pdf = PdfFileReader(file_content)
    # page = pdf.getPage(0).mediaBox
    # if page.getUpperRight_x() - page.getUpperLeft_x() > page.getUpperRight_y() - page.getLowerRight_y():
    #     print('Landscape')
    # else:
    #     print('Portrait')

    #Create the HTTP Response
    response = HttpResponse(file_content, content_type='application/pdf')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'inline; filename = {}'.format(filename)

    #Return
    return response
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add to your options to include

```
'orientation': 'Landscape'
```

such that

```
options = {
      'encoding': 'UTF-8',
      'javascript-delay':'10', #Optional
      'enable-local-file-access': None, #To be able to access CSS
      'orientation': 'Landscape'
      'page-size': 'A4',
      'custom-header' : [
          ('Accept-Encoding', 'gzip')
      ],
  }
```

Hope this helps!

Here is the resource I used:

https://wkhtmltopdf.org/usage/wkhtmltopdf.txt

Answer (score 0):

Using pyPDF4, I have done this using:

```
import PyPDF4

pdfReader = PyPDF4.PdfFileReader(open(source, 'rb'))

for page in range(pdfReader.numPages):
    pageObj = pdfReader.getPage(page)
    pageObj.rotateCounterClockwise(90)
```

or possibly use .rotateClockwise

The trick here is to know how much to if you really have landscape or portrait. Some pdf writers, in addition to the mediaBox, have a rotate property:

```
pdfReader.getPage(page).get('/Rotate')
```

which can be 90 instead of the expected 0 so your x and y will be out.  Good luck!